# Blender 3.6 - N and T Menus won't display

Tags: interface, customization

Blender 3.6 - I have a number of saved BLEND files - that refuse to open the N and T menus in any of the tabs. There is a little caret at the top that moves from the respective edge where the top of the menu should be - more towards the center when I press the N or T key. Clicking on the caret does nothing. I've tried opening the menus via menu selection - same deal. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe share a screenshot of your problem?